# How is Gamora this strong?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy, guardians-of-the-galaxy-2

In Guardians of the Galaxy, Vol. 2,

> Gamora picks up a gigantic gun that had been torn off of Nebula's ship. Gamora then carried the gun towards Nebula, while discharging a large amount of ordinance towards Nebula.  The gun itself must have weighed more than one ton. And then the discharge of the ordinance must have produced a massive backward pushing force.  No human could handle either the lift OR the discharge.

**How is Gamora strong enough to do this?**  I know that Thanos enhanced his daughters in order to make them better fighters. But is there also a more specific answer?

Comment: Women are uber tough. Just look at the armour they wear in video games...

Comment: “No human could handle the lift or the discharge.” I thought Gamora wasn’t human. You know, because of the green skin and the bright red hair.

Comment: @Adamant Of course she is inhuman. My point is simply to contrast. A reasonable answer could be that her home planet has very high gravity, so that her species seems much stronger on other planets. I am just asking for evidence.

Comment: This is a movie based on a comic book.  You know, comic books; that place where a man sized alien can hold up a falling skyscraper, rather than it just falling apart around him or crushing him, simply because his world has a different kind of star heating it up.

Answer (score 2):

Since the movie universe at least seems to have some form of inertial dampeners one could assume that the guns are built with inertial dampeners which either greatly reduces or completely removes the recoil, as to the weight of the weapons themselves super strength (as compared to regular humans) is not exactly uncommon in the marvel universe.

However as for canon evidence I am not sure if there is any schematics for weaponry that actually show a built in dampener.

Comment: The reason that I only+1'd this and did not mark it as accepted is that you do not provide any evidence.

Answer (score 1):

The planet is slightly larger than Earth's moon. Maybe since the gravitational pull is less than what she is accustomed to she can handle all of that. Otherwise with that kind of strength she should have been able to handle situations better in virtually every other instance.

It would also explain why all the guardians survived high falls on that planet.

Comment: This would certainly make sense from the lifting point of view. Wouldn't effect the recoil though. Admittedly walking should have "looked different" if this was the case. Still +1